# Installing Java 6 on Alpine

Tags: java, alpine-linux

I need to install Java 6 (preferably OpenJDK vs Oracle) in Alpine docker (latest) and I can't find an Alpine repository containing it. Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure why I got downvoted - it's a legitimate question

Comment: Why do you explicitly need Java 6?  Java 6 reached its end-of-life almost 7 years ago.  You're not likely to find what you're looking for.

Comment: For backwards compatibility perhaps? We still use windows XP to talk to very old PLCs. Assume it is a legit question.

Comment: @captcha Java 8 is backward compatible with Java 6...

Comment: Maybe he's using software that explicitly checks for a java version of 6 and doesn't run if it's different? What has caused you to doubt someone's question before knowing all the details?

Comment: @AndyDalton - for a legacy app that is not upgradeable to Java 7+ for various reasons, starting with no longer supported database drivers and like 100 other reasons. That app does not run on Java 8, even in legacy mode.

Comment: Get it here (from Oracle): https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-java-archive-javase6-downloads.html

Answer (score 0):

openjdk6 is in the alpine 2.7 repositories.
This version is no longer supported.
You can find the ISO(s) here:
http://ancient.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v2.7/releases/x86_64/

and the related packages (this link can be used as repository) here:
http://ancient.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v2.7/main/x86_64/

Hope it helps.

.: Francesco